# XSSF prefix for POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am not able to use XSSF prefix for POI . When i run the code following error is given . Please help me out

Error:run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
    at     javacodechefsummer.Javacodechefsummer.main(Javacodechefsummer.java:36)

Comment: PAckages imported: package javacodechefsummer;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

Answer (score 1):

The Apache POI website [has a whole section on the components and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), which a staggeringly high number of people seem to completely ignore... (Just look at the number of similar questions every week to see!)

If you care to take a [read through it](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), you'll clearly see the dependencies that are required by XSSF. These dependencies ship with Apache POI, you just need to add them to your classpath. From your error, you are missing `xmlbeans`, and possibly some others too

Answer (score 1):

if u r using  maven the dependencies are

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why would you use 3.8 beta 3? Surely 3.8 final at the very least, or even better 3.9 (the latest final release)